# Where can I find a full feature comparison of ADO Server 2020 vs ADO Services?

Tags: azure-devops

From the point of view of an team admin and user.

Particularly interested in planning tools and boards.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 1):

There is no such documentation. However, you can compare some features on this page: [Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline).

[image]

Additionally, Azure DevOps Service continually gets new features. To get new features on Azure DevOps Server, you have to update it.

Example of the last changes on the server on service:

[image]